# How to make Pydantic to automatically create a list from an iterable?

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a model:

```
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    items: List[Item]

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

And when I try to create instance with this:

```
my_model = MyModel.from_orm(foo)
```

pydantic is complaining that `foo.items is not a list` but it is an iterable so How can I tell pydantic to automatically **convert** it? I'm currently doing:

```
foo.items = list(foo.items)
my_model = MyModel.from_orm(foo)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pydantic does not automatically convert arbitrary iterable (but [does](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#infinite-generators) a generator) to a list. But as usual the [validator](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/) comes to the rescue:

```
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    items: List[int]

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

    @validator('items', pre=True)
    def iter_to_list(cls, v):
        return list(v)
```

Or in reusable form:

```
def iter_to_list(v):
    return list(v)


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    items: List[int]

    class Config:

    _items_to_list = validator('items', pre=True, allow_reuse=True)(iter_to_list)
```